# Open lightning component using isURLAddressable in a new tab without console navigation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have a usecase where a formula field on an object needs to open a lightning component in a new tab from standard navigation.

This lightning component currently implements the lightning:isURLAddressable interface however clicking on this link opens the lightning component in the same tab.

The reason for the formula field is that I don't believe there is a way to run a lightning component or action from related list records.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Salesforce bug and was resolved in "https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018PdwQAE&title=hyperlink-in-formula-field-doesn-t-respect-the-target-attribute-in-lightning"